# Disable prefix barcode scanner in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, barcode-scanner

I'm using `jquery.scannerdetection.js`.

When I am using it in firefox, I get a prefix "1"  (which I don't get in chrome and not in ie9-11).

When I try to disable it with "starchar: 49 "-  I can't manually type "1" in that text input.

At the moment I wrote a "work around" targeting mozilla, though I try to figure out what am I doing wrong.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 0;
    $(document).scannerDetection({
        onKeyDown: function (event) {

            return false;
        },
        startChar: [49],
        endChar: [13], 
        onComplete: function(barcode, qty){ 

           //my code
    });
});
```

Comment: I am still investigate this problem Though it seems the problem cause because the of my input and not the plugin.